# non-numeric argument to mathematical function error while rounding off particular column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rounding

I have a database table which I get into an R dataframe

```
Id   fName       lName     Personal_Number      Score   Country_Of_Birth
1    martin      Ingram    1-(939)-(106)-(9049) 59.099  Tanzania
2    trevor      Richards  1-(214)-(725)-(5955) 65.266  Eritrea
3    fitzgerald  Barron    1-(312)-(980)-(1499) 65.052  Kiribati
```

I only get to know which column to round-off at run time, the above example has only 1 such column however my table may have any number of column where rounding can be applied.

So my column name is a derived from variable `col`, my round off digits come from `ruleData` and I write:

```
mydataframe[[col]]  <- round(mydataframe[,col]), ruleData)
```

It gives me:

```
Error:Error in round(mydataframe[[col]]), ruleData): 
Error:  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I understand this is because the `round` function looks for a numeric vector, however when I try to check the mode in `mydataframe` I get:

```
                   Id            fName            lName          contact 
Output:       "numeric"      "character"      "character"      "character" 
Output:           Score Country_Of_Birth 
Output:       "numeric"      "character"
```

Problem:
- I have to use a dataframe so cant just change it to vector/matrix or data table.
- My column name and precision for round function always come from variables.
- Result should be the same `mydataframe`, with the `Score` values with 2 digits after decimal point( Note the values in Score now have 2 digits after decimal)

```
Id   fName       lName     Personal_Number      Score   Country_Of_Birth
1    martin      Ingram    1-(939)-(106)-(9049) 59.10  Tanzania
2    trevor      Richards  1-(214)-(725)-(5955) 65.27  Eritrea
3    fitzgerald  Barron    1-(312)-(980)-(1499) 65.05  Kiribati
```

Comment: Assuming the numbers are formatted correctly, just convert the column to numeric with `as.numeric()`.

Comment: Could the problem be ruleData? > round(2.459, digits = "f")
Error in round(2.459, digits = "f") : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: The `mydataframe[[col]])` part looks okay, so I think the problem must be ruleData.  The 'digits' argument of round() must be an integer. Is ruleData an integer scalar?

Comment: mikeck , I tried that but had seen same issue, however the good news is casting ruleData to numeric solved the issue, thanks you all for your responses.I never suspected ruleData as I was obsessed with the dataframe.

Comment: Can someone post it as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `@ladylala` and `@Santiago Capobianco`, Casting `ruleData` to `as.numeric` solved the issue.